# TextView Rotation on Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview, android-2.3-gingerbread

On Honeycomb and above I can easily rotate a TextView in degrees with this:

```
android:rotation(90)
```

But this doesn't work below Honeycomb, on Gingerbread and Froyo.

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the rotate animation in anim folder

below snippet will help you.

**textanim.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="10" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="50%"
        android:duration="100">
   </rotate>
```

**Inside code**

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.textanim));
```

Comment: is it possible to do this when the textview is on a Widget?